# loop through Pandas Dataframe and return columns name and type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I loop through Pandas Dataframe and return columns name and type?

```
#return types
for i in df.dtypes:
    print(i) 

# return column name
for col in df:
    print(col)
```

I'm able to return them separately but how can I return them from the same column?

Comment: If you want columns name and types then simply you can do df.dtypes . It will give you column name and type both which will server your purpose for column name and types. No need for columns and types separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
df.dtypes
```

Or if you're set on a loop:

```
for i, col in zip(df.dtypes, df):
    print(i, col)
```

Comment: Python's zip()  allows you to iterate over multiple iterables (lists, strings, etc.) at the same time via a single iterator object. It does this by returning an iterator of tuples.

Comment: I will iterate on df.dtypes and col will iterate on df. So will give you type, column name.